# Can i publish hello world app on play market?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing, recycle-bin

I buyed google developer account, and want to publish hello world app just for fun/for friends. Can google ban my account, if i do it? Will i use marking app as alpha to prevent search spam? How i can publish trash app for closed circle of users without punishment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: See [this](http://www.androidauthority.com/publishing-first-app-play-store-need-know-383572/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be ok if you publish `Hello World` app. But you better use unique package name.