# can i post an app that contains only ads, on google play store

Tags: android

its not what you think I can provide a reason for the user to press the button to view an ad and the reason is funny, will my account be terminated and the app will be deleted?
am asking this question because I saw an app that called this app is useless and it was really useless but it was not deleted out of the store
thx;

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer service question regarding policy; not a programming question

Comment: Aside from this being off-topic: You really have no content in your question at all, aside from talking vaguely about some issue you had, and repeating yourself a few times (as written, what you wrote really doesn't make any sense)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/topic/9877466?hl=en&ref_topic=9858052) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686328/can-i-publish-hello-world-app-on-play-market), you will come to the conclusion that it is possible to publish an app that contains only ads (If those ads are provided by google and do not contain content related to illegal activities etc.)

Comment: Please don't answer such questions. 1) the OP provided no programming details at all; 2) they just talked about some "useless" thing. At best, this is related to customer support and they can reach out. But it has nothing to do with Stack Overflow.